# How do I return a nested list of 2 words in Python?

Tags: python

For example I have a list of words like so `['word1,word2', 'word2,word3' 'word4,word4' ...]`

How can I return the list like this `[[word1,word2],[word3,word4],[word5,word6]...]`

Comment: you `split(',')` it ... -and you will get `[["word1","word2"], ... ]` - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Please include anything that you've tried so far.

Comment: ...and if you haven't tried anything, do that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `split()`

```
 l     = ['word1,word2', 'word2,word3' 'word4,word4']
 l_new = [x.split(',') for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zeeshan Akhter's solution is nice, and very efficient. List comprehensions tend to be a bit unreadable, though, and this solution is basically the same thing, spread out for readability.

```
l = ['word1,word2', 'word2,word3' 'word4,word4']
new = []
for item in l:
    new.append(item.split(','))
```